# Change the result that shown in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that has a column named result, the result is a variable that bank sent to me by post method... and the values are : 1, 2 ... so when the bank send to me 1 , I want show to the user its accepted, and if it was 2, show to the user its rejected... i need a if formulas that do the rest.

```
<?php
$id_get= $_POST['id_get'];
$trans_id = $_POST['trans_id'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "blah";
$password = "blah";
$dbname = "blah";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
<?php
mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id_get, trans_id, result FROM users");
echo "<table border='1' width='800' align='center'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>transaction Result</th>
</tr>";


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr align='center'>";
echo "<td width=10%>" . $row['id_get'] . "</td>";
echo "<td width=10%>" . $row['trans_id'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
 }
echo "</table>";?><br>
<div align="center">
<?php 

 mysqli_close($conn);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the value of `$row['result']` inside the `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))` block and display the content of `<td>` accordingly

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr align='center'>";
    echo "<td width=10%>" . $row['id_get'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td width=10%>" . $row['trans_id'] . "</td>";
    if ($row['result'] == '1') {
        echo "<td width=10%>Accepted</td>";
    }
    else if ($row['result'] == '2') {
        echo "<td width=10%>Rejected</td>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<td width=10%>Unknown</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

or alternatively you can change your query to this

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id_get, trans_id, (CASE WHEN result = 1 THEN 'Accepted' WHEN result = 2 THEN 'Rejected' ELSE 'Unknown' END) AS result_description FROM users");
```

and simply display `$row['result_description']`

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr align='center'>";
    echo "<td width=10%>" . $row['id_get'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td width=10%>" . $row['trans_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td width=10%>" . $row['result_description'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use case in PHP

```
$resultname= $row['trans_get'];
switch($resultname){
   case("1"):
         echo "Accepted";
   break;

   case("2"):
         echo "Rejected";
   break;

   default:
         echo "N/A";
   break;
}
```

So it should be something like:

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

   $resultname= $row['trans_get'];
    switch($resultname){
       case("1"):
             echo "Accepted";
       break;

       case("2"):
             echo "Rejected";
       break;
       default:
             echo "N/A";
       break;
    }    
    echo "<tr align='center'>";
    echo "<td width=10%>" . $row['id_get']. "</td>";
    echo "<td width=10%>" . $resultname . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` statement:

```
SELECT id_get, trans_id,
       (case when result = 1 then 'Accepted'
             when result = 2 then 'Rejected'
             else 'Unknown'
        end) as ResultString
FROM users;
```

You can also create a reference table in the database and use a `join`.  This is recommended for a real application, because it ensures that the same strings are used for any query.